# How would you Clear an Auth0 user session in a Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, auth0

I need help in clearing the user session in an Auth0 flutter app.
The problem is I have gone through the necessary procedures but whenever I log out from the app and log in again, I'm unable to enter the credentials to log me back into the app. It just logs me in as if the user session has been stored somewhere even after calling the `secureStorage.deleteAll()` function. I added the login prompt but the problem still persists.

Any help will be deeply appreciated

EDIT...
I'm using `flutter_secure_storage` and  `flutter_appauth` packages

Comment: Could you please tell more details? which login you use which package is use or which is mediator ?

Answer (score 1):

Clearing the application session is not enough, logout also from Auth0.

See step 2. [Auth0 Session Layer](https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/login/logout) for details.